# Administrador django admin.register

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy trabajando en el administrador de una aplicación, para el cual necesito agregar por `inlines` los modelos `PersonaNatural` y `PersonaJuridica`, la cuestión es solo puedo registrar el modelo `persona` una sola vez y los inline solo pueden ser usados con el modelo que posee la relación `OneToOneField`.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Persona(RegistroTiempo):
    tipo_identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False, choices=TIPO_IDENTIFICACION_CHOICES)
    identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True,
                                      verbose_name=_('identificación'))


class PersonaNatural(RegistroTiempo):
    persona = models.OneToOneField(Persona, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('nombres'))
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('apellidos'))
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('fecha de nacimiento'))
    lugar_nacimiento = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('lugar de nacimiento'))


class PersonaJuridica(RegistroTiempo):
    persona = models.OneToOneField(Persona, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('razón social'))
    fecha_registro = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('fecha de registro'),
                                      help_text=_('fecha de registro en camara y comercio'))
    fecha_inicio_operaciones = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False,
                                                verbose_name=_('fecha de inicio de operaciones'))
    representante_legal = models.ManyToManyField(PersonaNatural, null=True, blank=True,
                                                 verbose_name=_('representante legal'))
```

Archivo `admin.py`:

```
class PersonaNaturalInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = PersonaNatural
    fk_name = 'persona'

    fieldsets = (
        ('Información Basica', {
            'fields': ('nombres', 'apellidos', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'lugar_nacimiento'
                       )
        }),
    )


class PersonaJuridicaInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = PersonaJuridica
    fk_name = 'persona'

    fieldsets = (
        ('Información Basica', {
            'fields': ('razon_social', 'fecha_registro', 'fecha_inicio_operaciones', 'representante_legal'
                       )
        }),
    )


@admin.register(Persona)
class PersonaNaturalAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        ('Información Basica', {
            'fields': ('tipo_identificacion', 'identificacion',)
        }),
    )

    inlines = [PersonaNaturalInline,]
    readonly_fields = ['fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion']


@admin.register(Persona)
class PersonaJuridicaAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        ('Información Basica', {
            'fields': ('tipo_identificacion', 'identificacion',)
        }),
    )

    inlines = [PersonaJuridicaInline,]
    readonly_fields = ['fecha_creacion', 'fecha_modificacion']
```

¿Existe alguna forma para registrar dos veces un modelo?

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.